# Não consigo fazer com que dois modulos de um mesmo pacote se "reconheçam"

Tags: python, import

Boa noite, eu estou aprendendo mais sobre importação e criação de pacotes. Mas não consigo fazer com que dois modulos se "comuniquem", segue o link:

https://github.com/Gramosa/Importacao_teste

Se olhar os dois modulos functions.py e point.py na pasta plano_cartesiano, da pra ver que em cada arquivo existe a necessidade do outro (pois algumas funções e metodos nas classes retornam ou usam coisas do outro arquivo). Por exemplo no arquivo functions.py tem a classe Function que tem um método get_point(), esse metodo retorna um objeto Point, mas essa classe Point está no arquivo point.py. Dai para tentar interligar esses dois modulos, eu importei ambos no arquivo **init**.py que esta dentro da pasta plano_cartesiano. Então fora da pasta tem um arquivo teste.py que quando é rodado importa o pacote plano_cartesiano (como pode ser visto dentro do arquivo).
vou copiar aqui o texto do arquivo teste.py

```
from plano_cartesiano import *

a = Function(1, 2): #f(x) = x + 2
ponto1 = a.get_point(2)#f(x) = 2 + 2 = 4
#vai dar erro dizendo que Point não esta definido
```

Usando o mesmo exemplo para resumir a duvida, seria necessario que eu importasse tudo de functions.py em point.py e vice-versa? ou eu estou fazendo tudo errado? Desde já agradeço :)

Comment: O código deve estar contido na pergunta e não em um link. Caso um dia você decida apagar o repositório você invalidaria tanto a perguntas como as respostas. Coloque então um [MCVE] refletindo o problema proposto na pergunta.

Comment: mas o codigo esta dividido em varios arquivos diferentes, não sei como faria para postar aqui de forma organizada

Comment: Arquivo `mai.py: ......` Arquivo `con.py: ......`

Answer (score -2):

Posso estar errado, mas acredito que se você importar a classe Point no começo do código de functions.py, deve funcionar.